# riotjs trigger form onsubmit

Tags: javascript, forms, riot.js

So I have a simple form in RiotJS

```
<tag-form>
  <form onsubmit={handleSubmit} id='someForm'>
    <input name='param1' />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form">
  <script>
    this.handleSubmit=function(e) { console.log(e); }
  </script>
</tag-form>
```

That works just fine when I submit via the button. But when I use an external button to trigger the submit of the form

```
document.getElementById('someForm').submit();
```

it doesn't work because it somehow does not run the riotjs `onsubmit` function, but the native `submit` function, which is not what I want...

How to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some fiddling I fixed it like this:

```
<tag-form>
  <form onsubmit={handleSubmit} id='someForm'>
    <input name='param1' />
    <button type="submit" id="someButton">Submit</button>
  </form">
  <script>
    this.handleSubmit=function(e) { console.log(e); }
  </script>
</tag-form>
```

and then call `.click()` on the button, instead of `.submit()` on the form.

```
document.getElementById('someButton').click();
```

This seems to work fine!

Comment: You can alway call up the riot tag by doing `document.querySelector('tag-form')._tag`. This will give you access to the tag anywhere. Then you can call the `handleSubmit()` function programmatically, rather relying on an id/class being there.

Otherwise you can look at `observe()` which is cleaner than hunting down bound elements in the DOM. 

There are many ways to skin a cat though.